convert PS to exe file
This is my python script that i am trying to convert to exe file but it does not open
import re
from importlib import import_module
def remove_id_numbers(file_data):
    # Use re.sub to replace all instances of "id":XXXX with "id":
    # \d+ matches one or more digits
    return re.sub(r'"id":\d+', '"id":', file_data)

file_path = 'C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New folder/geofences.py'

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file_data = file.read()
file_data = remove_id_numbers(file_data)


file_data = file_data.replace('{"plc":"0.1v","markers":[],"routes":[],"zones":[', '{"plc":"0.1v","markers":[],"routes":[],"zones":[')

file_data = file_data.replace('{"group_name":"",', '{"group_name":"",')

# Define the range of values for lat from 37 down to 33
for i in range(37, 32, -1):
    # Replace occurrences of '{\"lat\":i.' with '{i.' in file_data
    file_data = file_data.replace(f'{{\\"lat\\":{i}.', f'{i}.')

# Define the range of values for lng from 47 down to 43
for i in range(47, 42, -1):
    # Replace occurrences of ',\"lng\":i.' with ',i.' in file_data
    file_data = file_data.replace(f',\\"lng\\":{i}.', f',{i}.')
file_data = file_data.replace(',', ',')


# Define the characters to be replaced
def replace_chars(file_data):
    chars_to_replace = '0123456789ABCDEFabcdef'
    index = 6 
    # Iterate over each character in chars_to_replace
    while True  :
        for char in chars_to_replace:
        # Replace occurrences of f'#{char}' with '#'
            file_data = file_data.replace(f'#{char}', '#')     
        index += -1  
        if index == 0:
            break 
    return file_data     
file_data = replace_chars(file_data)


file_data = file_data.replace('"color":"#","visible":"true","name_visible":"true","area":"0","vertices":"', '"color":"#","visible":"true","name_visible":"true","area":"0","vertices":"')


# find_string_in_file(file_path, search_string):
    #with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        # Read the file line by line
        #or line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
            # Check if the search string is in the line
            #if search_string in line:
                #print(f'Search string found at line {line_number}:')
                #print(line)

#search_string = '}]","polygon_color":"#","type":"polygon","radius":null,"center":null,"device_id":null'
#ind_string_in_file(file_path, search_string)

example_string = ' ", '
# Remove leading and trailing whitespace
stripped_string = example_string.strip()
print(stripped_string)

file_data = file_data.replace('",', '",')


example_string = ' "}]} '
# Remove leading and trailing whitespace
stripped_string = example_string.strip()
print(stripped_string)

file_data = file_data.replace('"}]}', '"}]}')

# Write the modified content back to the file
with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(file_data)

# Let's print out the new content to check the file
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print(file.read())



I used different methods to convert the above python script to exe file like pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe and cx_Freeze they all successfully created the exe file without any warning but the exe does not open, Why? What are the steps that i am missing? for the required dependencies how to install external dependencies manually?

What do you mean it doesn't open? Is it possible that it executes instantly and that you can't see it?

@MilosStojanovic no i don't think it executes then opens and closes instantly since there are some warnings that appear in warn-geofences.txt

@MilosStojanovic some of the warnings
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional, optional), shutil (delayed, optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (delayed, conditional, optional)
